# Django Rest Framework: Display object only for specific choice

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've got this serializers:

```
class PublicProgramSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Program
        fields = (
            ...
            'questions'
        )

    questions = CustomQuestionSerializer(source="custom_questions", many=True)
```

And:

```
class CustomQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomQuestion
        fields = (
            'label',
            'type',
            'scope'
        )
```

Now the 'scope' is a choice field with 3 options: `REGISTRATION`, `PARTICIPANT`, `EVENT` and I want to serialize only custom questions where the scope is set to `REGISTRATION`. How can I achieve that?

Thanks for any answer!

**Edit:** The models:

**Program.py**

```
class Program(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(u'Created', auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(u'Program Name', max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(u'Description', help_text=mark_safe(MARKDOWN_HELP_STRING), blank=True, null=True)
```

etc... Theres nothing really fancy about Program

**CustomQuestion.py**

```
class CustomQuestion(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        order_with_respect_to = 'program'

    SCOPE_REGISTRATION = "registration"
    SCOPE_PARTICIPANT = "participant"
    SCOPE_EVENT = "event"

    SCOPE_CHOICES = (
        (SCOPE_REGISTRATION, "Registration"),
        (SCOPE_PARTICIPANT, "Participant"),
        (SCOPE_EVENT, "Event"),
    )

    program = models.ForeignKey("Program", related_name="custom_questions")
    scope = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Scope",
        choices=SCOPE_CHOICES,
        null=False,
        max_length=50
    )
    description = models.CharField(
        verbose_name=u"Description",
        null=True, blank=True,
        max_length=100
    )
    label = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Label",
        null=False, blank=False,
        max_length=80
    )
```

And the Viewset for the Program:

```
class ProgramList(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = Program
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = PublicProgramSerializer
    queryset = Program.objects.exclude(visibility='hidden').filter(is_archived=False)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        programs = self.get_queryset()
        data = self.serializer_class(programs, context={'request': request}, many=True).data
        response = Response(data)
        response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache'
        return response

    def get_queryset(self):
        scope = self.request.GET.get('scope')
        if scope and scope in CustomQuestion.SCOPE_CHOICES:
            return Program.objects.filter(participant_questions__scope=scope)
        else:
            return Program.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a method called "get_queryset" in your viewset like this

```
class ProgramViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProgramSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        scope = self.request.GET.get('scope')
        if scope and scope in CustomQuestion.SCOPE_CHOICE:
            return Program.objects.filter(questions__scope=scope)
        else
            return Program.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        paginator = LimitOffsetPagination()
        if request.GET.get('limit'):
            page = paginator.paginate_queryset(self.get_queryset(), request)
            serializer = self.serializer_class(page, many=True)
            if page is not None:
                return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        else:
            serializer = self.serializer_class(self.get_queryset(), many=True)
        return response.Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: If I try using this the `scope` variable returns `None` for me sadly

Comment: How did you call this serializer?

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski Can you add your models to the question? this solution should work with a FK Field

Comment: @Bast I've added my models and also the viewset I'm using

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski You should use
return Program.objects.filter(custom_questions__scope=scope)
if the related name is "custom_questions"

Comment: @Bast well but my problem right now is that this bit of code is never called, scope is always "None" and then I just returns me the else part :/

Comment: @NikolaiNowolodski Try to use viewsets.ViewSet instead of generics.ListAPIView, donr forget to update your urls.py with something like that 
url(r'^programs/$',  ProgramViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'}), name='programs'),

Answer (score 0):

Well I have found a solution that works for me pretty well:

I didn't know that you can use a custom method as the `source` in the Serializer Method like:

```
questions = CustomQuestionSerializer(source="get_participant_questions", many=True)
```

So I just created the `get_participant_questions` method in my `program.py`, where I filtered for those exact questions:

```
def get_participant_questions(self):
        return self.custom_questions.filter(scope=CustomQuestion.SCOPE_PARTICIPANT)
```

and et voila my API showed me exactly what I wanted.

Thanks a lot @Bast, your answer helped me find this way :)